# Ubuntu 20 VM getting stuck showing Reached target cloud-init target

Tags: cloud-init

I am able to ssh to the host. But unable to get login Prompt on VMware web console.
As I have to clone the host so need login prompt to change its hostname and IP.
Had tried to disable cloud-init by creating a file /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled but after disabling it gets stuck at line "Finished update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"